# mysql auto increment and merging multiple databases into one master

Tags: mysql, increment, auto-increment

We have Master `Database A` and clients `DATABASE B` and `DATABASE C`.

Now  `Database A` is having `auto_increment = 10000` and `auto_increment_offset = 10000`.

We want my clients `DATABASE B` and `DATABASE C` setted with `auto_increment = 10001` and `auto_increment_offset = 10000` AND `auto_increment = 10002` and `auto_increment_offset = 10000` respectively to get merge with Master `Database A`.

My question is that above clients part is possible or not, if possible, what is the percentage of getting conflicts and how to avoid it.

Also,about performance that we are concerned as per table auto increment increases by 10000 at a time rather than typical increment by 1.

Answer (score 1):

We have done the opposite, don't interleave, but give them separate spaces:

```
Database A auto_increment = 10000000 for all tables
Database B auto_increment = 20000000
Database C auto_increment = 30000000
```

...and merge parts of Database C with Database B, etc, or how ever we like.  But we don't have much chance of conflict because the number of rows per database is relatively low < 10000, and this is not a master-slave situation.

Comment: Thanks, our major concern is about the productivity/performance. Will any of your suggested model or our model will have any performance issue.

Comment: There has been no performance issue for us, I don't think that your design will have a performance issue.

Comment: I swear I'd read negative reports about using non-sequential indexes, but I can't find anything definitive in a quick search.